# How to join in a new column without a primary key?

Tags: r, dplyr

my dplyr joining skills are a little rusty, but I'm trying to join two datasets that look like this:

```
L = c("a","a","a","a")
M = c("b","b","b","b")
N = c("c","c","c","c")
O = c("d","e","d","e")
P = c(1521,02915,12451,12)
DF1 <- data.frame(L,M,N,O,P)    

L = c("a","a","a","a")
M = c("b","b","b","b")
N = c("c","c","c","c")
O = c("d","e","f","d")
Q = c(11,8805,1231,9012)
DF2 <- data.frame(L,M,N,O,Q)
```

What's a good way to go about joining these so P and Q are together with the same LMNO columns?  I'm not sure if there's a way to generate a primary key to join on in dplyr or not.

I don't think it's a legal operation to do:

```
DF3 <- left_join(DF1,DF2)
```

since I lose the O column in DF2 from the resultant join. I feel like I'm missing something very simple here...

Comment: Why not try `merge(DF1,DF2)`??

Comment: If you want to keep all rows use `full_join` not `left_join`.

Comment: @DatamineR possible reasons: `merge` can be slower and it can mess with row order.

Comment: So `merge(DF1,DF2, all = TRUE)` is not what you want?

Comment: does full_join do the same task as merge(x, y, all = TRUE)?

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess yes

Answer (score -1):

If you want unique records based on the columns LMNO , Try this,

```
Select DF1.L, DF1.M, DF1.N , DF1.O , DF1.P , DF2.Q 
FROM DF1 JOIN DF2 
ON DF1.L = DF2.L 
AND DF1.M = DF2.M
AND DF1.N = DF2.N
AND DF1.0 = DF2.O
```

Comment: Not to burst your bubble, but I don't think the OP was asking for SQL code

Comment: I am sorry but I thought the question was a simple question and I gave a simple answer.